# JavaScript regexp: matching quoted substring without quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks something like

```
"Neo,Man,Cred,'Tred,Man,Ship',Manu"
```

Now I'm using the following regex

```
(,)(?=(?:[^']|'[^']*')*$)
```

for capturing the groups but it captures it as

```
Neo
Man
Cred
'Tred,Man,Ship'
Manu
```

What I want to achieve is removing that `'` (single quotes) from the string too using regex only. How to achieve that?

Comment: Which lang you're running?

Comment: javascript @AvinashRaj

Comment: What's wrong with looping through each content and removing single quote?

Comment: Right now I'm looping through and replacing the value but, I had a question about is there not a way to achieve it with single regex only @AvinashRaj

Comment: You can replace it. try `str = str.replage(/'/g,'')`. This will replace all occurrence. Note if you string has something like `Vicky's Post`, even this will be replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop using `exec`:

```
s = "Neo,Man,Cred,'Tred,Man,Ship',Manu";

r = /'(.*?)'|(\w+)/g; 
matches = [];
var match; 

while (match = r.exec(s)) {
  matches.push(match[1] || match[2]);
}
```

However, it makes just as much sense to use a simpler regexp, without the looping logic, and strip the quotes off afterward, as another person mentioned:

```
r2 = /'.*?'|\w+/g;
s.match(r2) . map(match => match.replace(/^'|'$/g, ''));
```

The reason you cannot do this with a single regexp is that `match` returns an array of complete matches, ignoring capturing groups. To create a complete match of a quoted substring without the quotes, you would need to use lookbehind, to ensure that the string is or is not preceded by a single quote. However, that is not possible in JS regexps. If you did have lookbehinds, you could write this as

```
/(?<=').*(?=')|\w+/
```

See https://regex101.com/r/aL6eA1/1.

Comment: Right now I'm looping through and replacing the value but, I had a question about is there not a way to achieve it with single regex only

Comment: To my knowledge, no. `match` returns an array of complete matches, ignoring capturing groups. To create a complete match of a quoted substring without the quotes, you would need to use negative lookbehind, to ensure that the string is not preceded by a single quote. However, that is not possible in JS regexps.

Comment: So is there any solution available within pcre @torazaburo

Comment: Thanks for the answer.